# Cannot implement quickchecks Arbitrary for my own type - "source trait is private"

Tags: rust

I am using [quickcheck](https://github.com/BurntSushi/quickcheck) to validate some properties of my code. At one point, I need an ASCII byte, so I tried to write an implementation of [`Arbitrary`](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/quickcheck/trait.Arbitrary.html) like this:

```
extern crate quickcheck;

use quickcheck::{quickcheck,Arbitrary,Gen};

#[derive(Debug,Copy,Clone)]
struct AsciiChar(u8);

impl Arbitrary for AsciiChar {
    fn arbitrary<G>(g: &mut G) -> AsciiChar
        where G: Gen
    {
        let a: u8 = g.gen_range(0, 128);
        AsciiChar(a)
    }
}

#[test]
fn it_works() {}
```

This fails with the error:

```
src/lib.rs:12:21: 12:40 error: source trait is private
src/lib.rs:12         let a: u8 = g.gen_range(0, 128);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Some searching led me to various bug reports ([1](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22050), [2](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24877), [3](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16264), [4](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21670)) that all seem to suggest I need to `use` the supertrait of [`Gen`](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/quickcheck/trait.Gen.html), which is [`rand::Rng`](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/rand/trait.Rng.html). I updated my crates and use statements to

```
extern crate quickcheck;
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;
use quickcheck::{quickcheck,Arbitrary,Gen};
```

But I continue to get the same error.

I've tried with

- `rustc version 1.1.0-dev (b402c43f0 2015-05-07) (built 2015-05-07)`
- `rustc 1.1.0-dev (3ca008dcf 2015-05-12) (built 2015-05-12)`

I'm also using `quickcheck v0.2.18`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, this was a tricky one. To progress in my testing, I added this hack:

```
impl Arbitrary for AsciiChar {
    fn arbitrary<G>(g: &mut G) -> AsciiChar
        where G: Gen
    {
        let a: u8 = Arbitrary::arbitrary(g);
        AsciiChar(a % 128)
    }
}
```

After that compiled, I got this error:

```
src/lib.rs:419:5: 419:23 error: use of unstable library feature 'rand': use `rand` from crates.io
src/lib.rs:419     extern crate rand;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/lib.rs:419:5: 419:23 help: add #![feature(rand)] to the crate attributes to enable
```

My problem was that **I forgot to add `rand` to my `Cargo.toml`**. I was thinking that I would just magically get the same version pulled in by quickcheck.

The ultimate problem was that I *hadn't* actually `use`d the correct version of `Rng`, the one that `Gen` was a subtrait of. Very confusing!

After adding `rand` to my `Cargo.toml`, I am back in business.

Comment: Oooo. Very nice! I had indeed added `rand` to `Cargo.toml`. I've been bitten by that same misconception previously, so I've internalized the need to to have all `extern crate blah;` statements correspond to an entry in `Cargo.toml`. :-) I also forgot that there is a `rand` crate that comes with Rust proper.

Comment: You should mark your answer as the answer. If other people get a similar error as you, hopefully this question will appear in their search.

Answer (score 1):

That's strange. I can reproduce your initial error, but your suggested fix works for me:

```
extern crate quickcheck;
extern crate rand;

use quickcheck::{Arbitrary,Gen};
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Debug,Copy,Clone)]
struct AsciiChar(u8);

impl Arbitrary for AsciiChar {
    fn arbitrary<G>(g: &mut G) -> AsciiChar
        where G: Gen
    {
        let a: u8 = g.gen_range(0, 128);
        AsciiChar(a)
    }
}

#[test]
fn it_works() {}
```

Running `cargo test` on both beta5 and the 2015-05-12 nightly works.