# How do I avoid 'source trait is private' when using subtraits?

Tags: rust, quickcheck

I'm trying to use [quickcheck](https://github.com/BurntSushi/quickcheck) in Rust. I want to define my enum as an instance of `Arbitrary`, so I can use it in tests.

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(quickcheck_macros)]

#[cfg(test)]
extern crate quickcheck;

use quickcheck::{Arbitrary,Gen};

#[derive(Clone)]
enum Animal {
    Cat,
    Dog,
    Mouse
}

impl Arbitrary for Animal {
    fn arbitrary<G: Gen>(g: &mut G) -> Animal {
        let i = g.next_u32();
        match i % 3 {
            0 => Animal::Cat,
            1 => Animal::Dog,
            2 => Animal::Mouse,
        }
    }
}
```

However, this gives me a compilation error:

```
src/main.rs:18:17: 18:29 error: source trait is private
src/main.rs:18         let i = g.next_u32();
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What causes this error? I know there's [this rust issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22050) but since `Gen` is imported I would think I could call `.next_u32`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203277/cannot-implement-quickchecks-arbitrary-for-my-own-type-source-trait-is-privat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Gen` has `rand::Rng` as a parent trait, the above works if you add `extern crate rand` after adding `rand = "*"` to your Cargo.toml.

[I also had to remove the `#[cfg(test)]` above the `quickcheck` import]